# React Native ExerciseDB API fetching all data, need to limit

Tags: node.js, react-native, api, fetch-api

I am currently working on a project using React Native which I will have to connect to the ExerciseDB API. The API work properly and can fetch the data from the API.

The data is successfully being fetched but the problem is it fetch all the data at once, but I want it to fetch a limited data at once and will load more when the user scroll down. I have try using limit but it is not working.

The below is my code for data fetching.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useFetch = (endpoint, limit) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/${endpoint}?limit=${limit}`,
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': API,
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com'
        },
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        try {
            const response = await axios.request(options);

            setData(response.data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error);
            alert('There is an error')
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const refetch = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        fetchData();
    }

    return { data, isLoading, error, refetch };
}

export default useFetch;
```

This is the result when I console.log(data)
Array(1324)[0 … 99][100 … 199][200 … 299][300 … 399][400 … 499][500 … 599][600 … 699][700 … 799][800 … 899][900 … 999][1000 … 1099][1100 … 1199][1200 … 1299][1300 … 1323]length: 1324[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

The below is the code to show the data from the API.

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router'

import styles from './searchworkouts.style'
import { COLORS, SIZES } from '../../../constants'
import WorkoutCard from '../../common/cards/workout/WorkoutCard'

import useFetch from '../../../hook/useFetch';

const Searchworkouts = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch('exercises', 10);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Workouts</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.headerBtn}>Show all</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.cardsContainer}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.primary} />
        ) : error ? (
          <Text style={styles.errorText}>Something went wrong</Text>
        ) : (
          data?.map((workout) => (
            <WorkoutCard />
          ))
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Searchworkouts
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. ExerciseDB does not support limit URL parameter. Use the `slice` or `splice` array method when you get all the data.